# Using sed to find inside of quotes and skip escaped quotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a curl call that queries JIRA REST API and returns a JSON string like the following (expect on a single line):

```
 {
    "expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog",
    "id":"36112","self":"https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/issue/36112",
    "key":"FOO-1218",
    "fields":
        {"summary":"the \"special\" field is not returning what is expected"}
 }
```

I was trying to parse out the "summary" field using this sed script:

```
sed 's/^.*summary":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

Which works fine if the "summary" doesn't have an escaped \" inside of it - but of course, with the escaped quote all I get back is from the example is:

```
the \
```

My desired output would either be:

```
the \"special\" field is not returning what is expected
```

Or even more fancily this:

```
the "special" field is not returning what is expected
```

It doesn't appear that I can do a lookbehind in sed, is there a simple way to solve this in a bash script?

Comment: And why would you not use a proper JSON parser to parse JSON?

Comment: @Jordan What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a JSON parser written in `sed`. Sorry, but this is insane.

Here's an example of a sane way to do this in python:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(JIRA_API_ENDPOINT, headers = JIRA_HEADERS)
obj = response.json()
obj['fields']['summary']
```

There's also a good JIRA API wrapper in python, called jira-python. Just use that and you wont have to do any parsing at all. I've used it to good effect before. Link here: http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Your coworkers will thank you.

Comment: *+1* for the sane way to do it.

Comment: After struggling with multiple attempts at using sed to do this, I think I finally have to give in that it's insane and the best solution is to use a command line JSON option like Python, Perl or other options.

Answer (score 1):

For the inside of double quotes, you really want at least one of these facilities:

1. lookarounds (so you can check that what precedes and follows are quote).
2. `\K` (so you can drop the opening quote)
3. the ability to examine capture groups (so you can match the whole quote, but only capture what's inside).

Typically, you would want something like this:

```
(?<=(?<!\\)")(?:\\"|[^"])*(?=")
```

In `grep -P` mode, which uses `PCRE`, you can tap into even more features, such as the possessive quantifier I'll add here:

```
(?<=(?<!\\)")(?:\\"|[^"])*+(?=")
```

Note that the `[^"]` can normally run across multiple lines, which you'd typically control with `[^"\r\n]`, but `grep` only looks line by line anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For this limited case, you could use something like

```
vnix$ sed -n 's/.*summary":"\(\([^\\"]*\|\\.\)*\)".*/\1/p' file.json
the \"special\" field is not returning what is expected
```

Inside the quoted string, double quotes are disallowed, except any character is allowed immediately after a literal backslash.  The character class disallows backslashes, too, to prevent a backslash from "leaking" into the wrong partial match.  The repeat after the character class is just an optimization to avoid needless backtracking.

Any attempt at generalizing this will quickly become quite unwieldy.  The [Friedl book](http://regex.info/book.html) has an example which stretches over more than a page just to illustrate the futility of this.

Comment: This isn't working for me and I don't know why not.  I tried (osx) and just got a blank line:
`echo '{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog","id":"36112","self":"https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/issue/36112","key":"FOO-1218","fields":{"summary":"the \"special\" field is not returning what is expected"}}' | sed -n 's/.*summary":"\(\([^\\"]*\|\\.\)*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: I made a minor tweak but I don't have an OSX to test on right now, so this is speculative.  Does adding a `"` to the trailing expression help? (See edit.)

Comment: No, still getting back a blank line from the udpated expression `echo '{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelo‌​g","id":"36112","self":"https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/issue/36112","key":"F‌​OO-1218","fields":{"summary":"the \"special\" field is not returning what is expected"}}' | sed -n 's/.*summary":"\(\([^\\"]*\|\\.\)*\)".*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0):

After serious struggling, I have figured out a method that is working for this very specific use-case.  I convern the escaped quotes (\") into an even more obscure character sequence of five underscores (**_**), do the regex, and then convert it back:

```
sed -e 's/\\"/_____/g' -e 's/^.*summary":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/' -e 's/_____/"/g'
```

So the full test looks like this:

```
echo '{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelo‌​g","id":"36112","self":"https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/issue/36112","key":"F‌​OO-1218","fields":{"summary":"the \"special\" field is not returning what is expected"}}' | sed -e 's/\\"/_____/g' -e 's/^.*summary":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/' -e 's/_____/"/g'
```

And the output looks like this:

```
the "special" field is not returning what is expected
```